# advanced use of find and replace

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have classes with many, many empty methods called getFieldNameX or getFieldNameY (implementing a big interface for many columned linq to sql tables). I want to insert return values using find and replace.

This is that have

```
Function GetInsertedDate() as Date implements myInterface.getInsertedDate 

End Function
```

This is what I want:

```
Function GetInsertedDate() as Date implements myInterface.getInsertedDate 
    return me.insertedDate    //"return me." + method signature minus get
End Function
```

Is there any way to do this with find and replace?

Comment: It may take a little bit of time to tune the expression but it can be done with regular expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Find: myInterface\.get{.+}\n\n

Replace: myInterface.get\1\n\treturn me.\1\n

Use: Regular expressions
```

Comment: @Dialecticus--you just saved me so much time!

Answer (score 0):

search for `getInsertedDate`
and replace with `getInsertedDate\n\treturn me.insertedDate` with Use: Regular expressions enabled